# Magento 2 : How to create a ConverToCsv.php for company admin grid export?

Tags: magento2, grid, csv

I want to create a custom export csv file for company grid.I got to know that we can create ConvertToCsv.php to do that. Can someone explain steps on how to do that?

Comment: do you want to add export option in admin grid??

Comment: @Chikku yes, also I want to have few columns which are present in the grid to be not in the export and 1/0 to be shown as yes/No in the export..basically, I want a customized export in the admin grid

Comment: did you tried my ans

Answer (score 1):

You can add exportButton to your custom grid.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-exportbutton.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644662/magento2-export-button-csv-in-custom-grid

Answer (score 1):

**follow my steps:-**

create your controller and add below code in to it
**ExportCsv.php**

```
<?php
namespace Yourpackage\Yourmodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Sample;

class ExportCsv extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
  protected $_fileFactory;
  protected $_response;
  protected $_view;
  protected $directory;
  protected $converter;
  protected $resultPageFactory ;
  protected $directory_list;
  public function __construct( \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context  $context,
         \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory  = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
}
 public function execute()
 {
    $fileName = 'yourfilename.csv';
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory ->create();
    $content = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('yourblockname')->getCsv();;
    $this->_sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content);

 }

protected function _sendUploadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType='application/octet-stream') {

     $this->_response->setHttpResponseCode(200)
        ->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true)
        ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true)
        ->setHeader('Content-type', $contentType, true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($content), true)
        ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"', true)
        ->setHeader('Last-Modified', date('r'), true)
        ->setBody($content)
        ->sendResponse();
    die;

 }
}
```

**Now just create your layout xml** `yourmodule_yourcontroller_exportcsv`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="yourmodule_yourcontroller_grid"/>
</page>
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Is this code working for you?